# in R code; in a data frame(size 195 x 195), in a row corresponding columns minimum value related row name and column name

Tags: r

```
STOP_ID STP1    STP2    STP3    STP4    STP5    STP6
DEP1    10      518     497     131     16      131
DEP2    510     22      32      452     510     452
DEP3    487     27      45      439     487     430
DEP4    132     466    445      32      132     62
DEP5    43      518    487      131     55      483
DEP6    132     466    445      32      132     25
```

I am expecting 
rowname: DEP1, columnname: STP1  Minimum Value: 10

Can someone help me to get the above answer

Comment: look at `which.min()`

Comment: I am getting minimum value from  given row

Comment: but I want the rowname i.e DEP1, and minimum value corresponding columnname i.e. STP1 and then Minimum Value 10.

Comment: i have added the answer @Keerthy

Answer (score 2):

We can do this using vectorized option with `max.col`

```
j1 <- max.col(-df1[-1], "first")
res <- transform(df1, min_val = df1[-1][cbind(1:nrow(df1), j1)], 
                                            col_name = names(df1)[-1][i1])
res
#    STOP_ID STP1 STP2 STP3 STP4 STP5 STP6 min_val col_name
#1    DEP1   10  518  497  131   16  131      10     STP1
#2    DEP2  510   22   32  452  510  452      22     STP2
#3    DEP3  487   27   45  439  487  430      27     STP2
#4    DEP4  132  466  445   32  132   62      32     STP4
#5    DEP5   43  518  487  131   55  483      43     STP1
#6    DEP6  132  466  445   32  132   25      25     STP6
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[melt(setDT(df1), id.var = "STOP_ID", variable.name = "col_name",
         value.name = "min_val")[, .SD[which.min(min_val)], STOP_ID]
           , on = "STOP_ID"]
#    STOP_ID STP1 STP2 STP3 STP4 STP5 STP6 col_name min_val
#1:    DEP1   10  518  497  131   16  131     STP1      10
#2:    DEP2  510   22   32  452  510  452     STP2      22
#3:    DEP3  487   27   45  439  487  430     STP2      27
#4:    DEP4  132  466  445   32  132   62     STP4      32
#5:    DEP5   43  518  487  131   55  483     STP1      43
#6:    DEP6  132  466  445   32  132   25     STP6      25
```

If we need only 'STOP_ID', 'min_val' and 'col_name'

```
melt(setDT(df1), id.var = "STOP_ID", variable.name = "col_name", 
            value.name = "min_val")[, .SD[which.min(min_val)], STOP_ID]
#    STOP_ID col_name min_val
#1:    DEP1     STP1      10
#2:    DEP2     STP2      22
#3:    DEP3     STP2      27
#4:    DEP4     STP4      32
#5:    DEP5     STP1      43
#6:    DEP6     STP6      25
```

Answer (score 1):

```
apply(df[2:7], 1, function(x) colnames(df[2:7])[which.min(x)])
# [1] "STP1" "STP2" "STP2" "STP4" "STP1" "STP6"
apply(df[2:7], 1, function(x) x[which.min(x)])
# [1] 10 22 27 32 43 25
```

add these above vectors to new columns if that is what you are looking for.

```
x = apply(df[2:7], 1, function(x) colnames(df[2:7])[which.min(x)])
y = apply(df[2:7], 1, function(x) x[which.min(x)])
df$min_vale = y
df$col_name = x

# df
#  STOP_ID STP1 STP2 STP3 STP4 STP5 STP6 min_vale col_name
#1    DEP1   10  518  497  131   16  131       10     STP1
#2    DEP2  510   22   32  452  510  452       22     STP2
#3    DEP3  487   27   45  439  487  430       27     STP2
#4    DEP4  132  466  445   32  132   62       32     STP4
#5    DEP5   43  518  487  131   55  483       43     STP1
#6    DEP6  132  466  445   32  132   25       25     STP6
```

another method using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
df1 = setDT(df)[, apply(.SD, 1, function(x) list(colnames(df[2:7])[which.min(x)], x[which.min(x)])),
            .SDcols = colnames(df)[2:7]]
colnames(df1) = df$STOP_ID
# df1
#      DEP1 DEP2 DEP3 DEP4    DEP5 DEP6
#1: STOP_ID STP1 STP1 STP3 STOP_ID STP5
#2:      10   22   27   32      43   25
```

Comment: but I want the rowname i.e DEP1, and minimum value corresponding columnname i.e. STP1 and then Minimum Value 10.  second row : rowname DEP2 ; Column name: STP2 and value 22 ; third row: rowname DEP3 column name : STP2 and value 27 ...

Comment: that is what you are getting above. Look at the first column and the last 2 columns. You can remove the unwanted columns by assigning it NULL

Comment: i need to cluster all 6 stops minimum values that is why i need to check the column name then create 6 arrays and then push the value to respective array (out of six STP1 to 6 )

Comment: @Keerthy edit your original question to include the format of your expected output. You want it as a `list`? as a `data.frame`? etc

Comment: Thank you a lot joel wilson... can I apply the function only on few columns out of 195 columns like I want to check first 6 columns only from row 7 onward for every given row my understanding is x = apply(df[-1], 2:7, function(x) colnames(df[-1])[which.min(x)])
y=apply(df[-1], 7, function(x) x[which.min(x)])

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using `dplyr` and `tidyr`,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(c.names, value, STP1:STP6) %>%
  group_by(STOP_ID) %>% 
  filter(value == min(value)) %>%  
  arrange(value) %>% 
  rename(r.names = STOP_ID)

#Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
#Groups: r.names [6]

#  r.names c.names value
#   <fctr>   <chr> <int>
#1    DEP1    STP1    10
#2    DEP2    STP2    22
#3    DEP6    STP6    25
#4    DEP3    STP2    27
#5    DEP4    STP4    32
#6    DEP5    STP1    43
```